# Vue Stripe checkout error "TypeError: this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I am testing the Vue Stripe Checkout from: https://docs.vuestripe.com/vue-stripe/stripe-checkout/one-time-payment
And i am getting this error in console: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout is not a function", here is the code (i'm using product y test key), already checkout client integration is enable, and i am testing it in localhost, stripe docs say in test mode works with any domain:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <stripe-checkout
      ref="checkoutRef"
      mode="payment"
      :pk="publishableKey"
      :line-items="lineItems"
      :success-url="successURL"
      :cancel-url="cancelURL"
      @loading="v => loading = v"
    />
    <button @click="submit">Pay now!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { StripeCheckout } from '@vue-stripe/vue-stripe';
export default {
  components: {
    StripeCheckout,
  },
  data () {
    //this.publishableKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
    this.publishableKey = 'pk_test_wkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxC00bSQO9djj';
    return {
      loading: false,
      lineItems: [
        {
          // price: 'some-price-id', // The id of the one-time price you created in your Stripe dashboard
          price: 'price_1KxXxxxxxxxxxxT2bZ'
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      successURL: 'your-success-url',
      cancelURL: 'your-cancel-url',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      // You will be redirected to Stripe's secure checkout page
      this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this prebuilt vuestripe in a child component, when i changed to an parent component, the error did not came up again. @RyanM, thnxs.

Answer (score 0):

This error can mean a lot of this but often this is due to Stripe not being initialized.

I would log the `process.env.STIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` value to ensure you are passing the Publishable Key from your [Stripe Account](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys).

Additionally, if Vue-Stripe bundles the creation of the [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers) it will likely fail if you use a non-existent Price ID.

Ensure you are passing your PK properly and using valid Price IDs from your Stripe account.

Comment: RyanM thxs for answer. Already verified my test public key and test product key, and still not working.

Comment: i just edited how looks like the pk and product key in the code.